# Understanding Kotlin Type system, What is meant by `{Comparable<{ Double & Int }> & Number}` and how to work with that

Tags: kotlin, types, interface, multiple-inheritance

So for example:

```kotlin
var a = true
val test = if (a) -1 else -3.2
```

I was expecting the Type of the `test` should be the most closest intersection of the type-hierarchy i.e. for Int and Double is `Number`.

But looking at the IDE, it seems to have a type of `{Comparable<{ Double & Int }> & Number}`.

[image: IDE Snapshot]

And the weird thing is, I cannot specify it like that (since {} is reserved for creating lambdas), I can only set it to a type of `Number`.

And another wierd thing is that if I try some function from Comparable interface, it throws some error:

```kotlin
// Warning at value 2
// The integer literal does not conform to the expected type {Double & Int}
test.compareTo(2)

3.compareTo(-1.1) // possible
2.3.compareTo(100) // possible

// But why not this is possible, while it has inferred type of Comparable?
test.compareTo(2)
```

Could somebody help in understanding the concept here? And few questions:

- How does that type work all together, i.e. how could one variable hold two types at once?
- How could one specify that type explicitly?
- How do you use functions from Comparable interface, when test has implementaion of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` here means an intersection type (which isn't supported in the Kotlin language itself, but the compiler uses them internally). You can see it mentioned in the (incomplete) [specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#intersection-types).

> Intersection types are special non-denotable types used to express the fact that a value belongs to all of several types at the same time.

"Non-denotable" means exactly that you can't specify that type. I am not sure but I think the extra `{` `}` in types are supposed to indicate exactly this.

In particular, `Comparable<Double & Int>` means you can only compare `test` to something which is *both* `Double` and `Int`, but there are no such values. The compiler could probably simplify it to `Comparable<Nothing>`.

> the most closest intersection of the type-hierarchy i.e. for `Int` and `Double` is `Number`.

1. It's least upper bound, which is closer to union, not intersection. The specification actually calls it "union types", but that's not the normal usage of that term.
2. This least upper bound is not `Number` because it *also* takes least upper bound of the `Comparable` interfaces which works out to `Comparable<Double & Int>` because `Comparable` is contravariant:

   ```
    lub(Int, Double) = 
    Number & lub(Comparable<Int>, Comparable<Double>) =
    Number & Comparable<Int & Double>
   ```

This calculation is described under [type decaying](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#type-decaying):

> All union types are subject to type decaying, when they are converted to a specific intersection type, representable within Kotlin type system.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1 is that the compiler is doing its best to infer the type, inventing new constraints to describe it as it goes.

The answer to question 2 is that you cannot.

The answer to question 3 is that you cannot, because `Int` is not comparable to `Double` and vice versa.  So none of the methods from `Comparable` are actually usable, but the value definitely implements `Comparable` against *something*.  This is not useful for `Comparable`, but could be for another interface.  For example, imagine:

```
interface ZeroAndComparable<T> {
  fun compareTo(t: T): Int
  fun zero(): T
}

val foo : ZeroAndComparable<Int> = someZeroAndComparableInt()
val bar : ZeroAndComparable<Double> = someZeroAndComparableDouble()
val foobar = if (a) foo else bar
val zero : Any = foobar.zero() // should work
foobar.compareTo(something) // cannot work
```